# Matplotlib x axis date formatting ConciseDateFormatter increase font size of minor tick year

Tags: python, matplotlib, date-formatting

How can I increase the font size of the year?
The basic x-ticks are increased, but not the year.

[image]

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick


df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-10'], 'foo':[1,3]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dt)
df = df.set_index(['dt'])

plt.figure(figsize = (4, 4))

aut_locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
aut_formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(aut_locator)

ax = df.foo.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(aut_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(aut_formatter)
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(fontsize=29)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That text on the lower right is the "axes offset". You can access it as `ax.xaxis.get_offset_text()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-10'], 'foo':[1,3]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dt)
df = df.set_index(['dt'])

plt.figure(figsize = (4, 4))

aut_locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
aut_formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(aut_locator)

ax = df.foo.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(aut_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(aut_formatter)
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(fontsize=29)
ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_size(29)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]